# Why session always auto generate after loading a page in laravel 5?

Tags: php, session, laravel

I start to work with my project using laravel 5. I realized that it work fine in my local directory with session after I login to my site, But I just know that I got problem when I hosted my project to server. After I login each time, the session could not remember that cause the problem to me.

**PHP Login**

```
public function postLogin(){
    $hit = 0;
    if(Request::ajax()){
        $pw = Request::input('pw');
        if(!empty($pw)){
            $admin_pass = AdminPassword::first(['admin_pass']);
            $ip_address = Request::ip();
            if(!empty($admin_pass) && trim($admin_pass->admin_pass) == trim($pw)){
                if(Auth::attempt(['username' => Request::input('username'), 'password' => Request::input('password'),'status'=>1])){
                    try{
                        $user = Auth::user();
                        $user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $user->login_ip = $ip_address;
                        $user->save();
                        $permissions = Auth::user()->permission;
                        if(!empty($permissions) && count($permissions) >0){
                            session(['ROLE_PERMISSION'=>$permissions]);
                        }
                        $failed = FailedLogin::whereRaw('ip_address = INET_ATON(\''.$ip_address.'\')')->first();
                        if(!empty($failed)){
                            $failed->delete();
                        }
                    }catch (\Exception $ex){}
                    $url = Request::session()->pull('url.intended', '/');
                    return ['url'=>$url,'msg'=>'Successfully.','status'=>true,'hit'=>$hit];
                }else{
                    $hit = $this->updateFailedLogin($ip_address,Request::input('username'));
                }
            }else{
                $hit = $this->updateFailedLogin($ip_address,Request::input('username'));
            }
        }
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
    return ['url'=>'','msg'=>'Try again.','status'=>false,'hit'=>$hit];
}
```

**Here is my .env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=RpmO55Jcq2HHq5foQ6O9Vf5e8wjbbKZs

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=testing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

Any helps would be really appreciate.

Thank you very much.

Comment: May be is your production env. load balanced?

Comment: @ArneRie - Could you detail your suggestion?

Comment: Please see the edited question above.

Comment: If it's load balanced there must be something like sticky session on it. Could it be that you're IP is masqueraded that it changes from time to time?

Comment: @Tux Dictumst - Sorry sir, I don't get your message. Can you give me more detail?

Comment: Am I correct that you are checking the IP of the user?

Comment: Yes, you are right. and what's wrong if I want to check IP of the user?

Comment: and am I correct that on every page you are checking current IP and compare it with `$use->login_ip`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83707/discussion-between-tux-dictumst-and-tum-lina).